# NuGet package issues while upgrading Power Platform Dataverse NuGet Package to latest stable version

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nuget, dataverse, power-platform

I am using Azure Functions V4 and connecting to Dataverse to handle database operations.  I am trying to upgrade my Dataverse NuGet Package 1.0.23 to  latest stable version (1.1.12).

After upgrading, I started to test my azure functions, which caused some dependency issues on existing NuGet packages.

**Issue1:** While trying to connect to dataverse service client , I faced this issue.

Method not found: 'Void `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`.MemoryCache..ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCacheOptions>)'.

**Fixed:**  By installing `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching` NuGet Package.

**Issue2:** This issue is causing when I am trying to call any method that existed in Domain/Bussiness project.
My domain/business project is a `C#` library project.

Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.get_Item(System.String)

I tried to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives` package, but I am still facing the same problem if I run any API.

**Note:**  There were no changes to any API only upgraded NuGet Package.

My `.csproj` looks like below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client" Version="1.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="shortid" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.32.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Business.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Dataver service client connecting in `Configure` method of `startup.cs`

```
 //Dataverse Database Connection Binding.
            string connectionString = $"AuthType={configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings")["DataverseAuthType"]};ServiceUri={configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings")["DataverseBaseUri"]};ClientId={configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings")["DataverseClientId"]};ClientSecret={configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings")["DataverseClientSecret"]};";
            builder.Services
               .AddSingleton<IOrganizationServiceAsync2>(_ =>
                   new ServiceClient(connectionString));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.get_Item(System.String)

***Check if below steps help to fix the issue:***

- As you already have the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` of version 7.0.1, install `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives` Package with version `7.0.0` in your application.

[image]

**(or)**

- Downgrade the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` Package to `6.0.0`.
- Try installing  `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives` Package with version `6.0.0` to fix the issue.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="6.0.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" Version="6.0.0" />   
</ItemGroup>
```

**References:**

['Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.get_Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/338076/method-not-found-microsoft-extensions-primitives-s)